# ERROR: Could not build wheels for yolov4, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python

I'm trying to install yolov4 via pip on my VSCode. But i receive this error

pip install yolov4
Collecting yolov4
Using cached yolov4-3.2.0.tar.gz (42 kB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting numpy>=1.18.0
Using cached numpy-1.23.4-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (17.1 MB)
Building wheels for collected packages: yolov4
Building wheel for yolov4 (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Building wheel for yolov4 (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [118 lines of output]
/tmp/pip-build-env-7xavfwot/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py:771: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'long-description' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'long_description' instead
warnings.warn(
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/yolov4
copying py_src/yolov4/**init**.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/yolov4
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/yolov4/common
copying py_src/yolov4/common/media.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/yolov4/common
copying py_src/yolov4/common/config.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/yolov4/common
copying py_src/yolov4/common/parser.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/yolov4/common
copying py_src/yolov4/common/**init**.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/yolov4/common
copying py_src/yolov4/common/base_class.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/yolov4/common
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/yolov4/tf
copying py_src/yolov4/tf/model.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/yolov4/tf
copying py_src/yolov4/tf/**init**.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/yolov4/tf
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/yolov4/tflite
copying py_src/yolov4/tflite/**init**.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/yolov4/tflite
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/yolov4/common/metalayer
copying py_src/yolov4/common/metalayer/base_layer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/yolov4/common/metalayer
copying py_src/yolov4/common/metalayer/convolutional_layer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/yolov4/common/metalayer
copying py_src/yolov4/common/metalayer/shortcut_layer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/yolov4/common/metalayer
copying py_src/yolov4/common/metalayer/maxpool_layer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/yolov4/common/metalayer
copying py_src/yolov4/common/metalayer/net_layer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/yolov4/common/metalayer
copying py_src/yolov4/common/metalayer/route_layer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/yolov4/common/metalayer
copying py_src/yolov4/common/metalayer/upsample_layer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/yolov4/common/metalayer
copying py_src/yolov4/common/metalayer/yolo_tpu_layer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/yolov4/common/metalayer
copying py_src/yolov4/common/metalayer/**init**.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/yolov4/common/metalayer
copying py_src/yolov4/common/metalayer/yolo_layer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/yolov4/common/metalayer
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/yolov4/tf/utils
copying py_src/yolov4/tf/utils/weights.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/yolov4/tf/utils
copying py_src/yolov4/tf/utils/mAP.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/yolov4/tf/utils
copying py_src/yolov4/tf/utils/**init**.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/yolov4/tf/utils
copying py_src/yolov4/tf/utils/tflite.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/yolov4/tf/utils
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/yolov4/tf/training
copying py_src/yolov4/tf/training/iou.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/yolov4/tf/training
copying py_src/yolov4/tf/training/**init**.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/yolov4/tf/training
copying py_src/yolov4/tf/training/yolo_loss.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/yolov4/tf/training
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/yolov4/tf/dataset
copying py_src/yolov4/tf/dataset/keras_sequence.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/yolov4/tf/dataset
copying py_src/yolov4/tf/dataset/augmentation.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/yolov4/tf/dataset
copying py_src/yolov4/tf/dataset/**init**.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/yolov4/tf/dataset
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/yolov4/tf/layers
copying py_src/yolov4/tf/layers/convolutional_layer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/yolov4/tf/layers
copying py_src/yolov4/tf/layers/shortcut_layer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/yolov4/tf/layers
copying py_src/yolov4/tf/layers/maxpool_layer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/yolov4/tf/layers
copying py_src/yolov4/tf/layers/route_layer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/yolov4/tf/layers
copying py_src/yolov4/tf/layers/upsample_layer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/yolov4/tf/layers
copying py_src/yolov4/tf/layers/yolo_tpu_layer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/yolov4/tf/layers
copying py_src/yolov4/tf/layers/**init**.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/yolov4/tf/layers
copying py_src/yolov4/tf/layers/yolo_layer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/yolov4/tf/layers
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/yolov4/tf/training/callbacks
copying py_src/yolov4/tf/training/callbacks/save_weights.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/yolov4/tf/training/callbacks
copying py_src/yolov4/tf/training/callbacks/yolo_each_step.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/yolov4/tf/training/callbacks
copying py_src/yolov4/tf/training/callbacks/**init**.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/yolov4/tf/training/callbacks
running build_ext
gcc -pthread -B /home/dennisgarcia/anaconda3/envs/crop_env/compiler_compat -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/dennisgarcia/anaconda3/envs/crop_env/include -I/home/dennisgarcia/anaconda3/envs/crop_env/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/dennisgarcia/anaconda3/envs/crop_env/include -fPIC -I/home/dennisgarcia/anaconda3/envs/crop_env/include/python3.9 -c flagcheck.cpp -o flagcheck.o -std=c++17
gcc: fatal error: cannot execute ‘cc1plus’: execvp: Arquivo ou diretório inexistente
compilation terminated.
gcc -pthread -B /home/dennisgarcia/anaconda3/envs/crop_env/compiler_compat -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/dennisgarcia/anaconda3/envs/crop_env/include -I/home/dennisgarcia/anaconda3/envs/crop_env/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/dennisgarcia/anaconda3/envs/crop_env/include -fPIC -I/home/dennisgarcia/anaconda3/envs/crop_env/include/python3.9 -c flagcheck.cpp -o flagcheck.o -std=c++14
gcc: fatal error: cannot execute ‘cc1plus’: execvp: Arquivo ou diretório inexistente
compilation terminated.
gcc -pthread -B /home/dennisgarcia/anaconda3/envs/crop_env/compiler_compat -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/dennisgarcia/anaconda3/envs/crop_env/include -I/home/dennisgarcia/anaconda3/envs/crop_env/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/dennisgarcia/anaconda3/envs/crop_env/include -fPIC -I/home/dennisgarcia/anaconda3/envs/crop_env/include/python3.9 -c flagcheck.cpp -o flagcheck.o -std=c++11
gcc: fatal error: cannot execute ‘cc1plus’: execvp: Arquivo ou diretório inexistente
compilation terminated.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/dennisgarcia/anaconda3/envs/crop_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 363, in 
main()
File "/home/dennisgarcia/anaconda3/envs/crop_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 345, in main
json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
File "/home/dennisgarcia/anaconda3/envs/crop_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 261, in build_wheel
return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
File "/tmp/pip-build-env-7xavfwot/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 412, in build_wheel
return self._build_with_temp_dir(['bdist_wheel'], '.whl',
File "/tmp/pip-build-env-7xavfwot/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 397, in _build_with_temp_dir
self.run_setup()
File "/tmp/pip-build-env-7xavfwot/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 335, in run_setup
exec(code, locals())
File "", line 58, in 
File "/tmp/pip-build-env-7xavfwot/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/**init**.py", line 87, in setup
return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
File "/tmp/pip-build-env-7xavfwot/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 185, in setup
return run_commands(dist)
File "/tmp/pip-build-env-7xavfwot/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 201, in run_commands
dist.run_commands()
File "/tmp/pip-build-env-7xavfwot/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 968, in run_commands
self.run_command(cmd)
File "/tmp/pip-build-env-7xavfwot/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1217, in run_command
super().run_command(command)
File "/tmp/pip-build-env-7xavfwot/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 987, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
File "/tmp/pip-build-env-7xavfwot/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 299, in run
self.run_command('build')
File "/tmp/pip-build-env-7xavfwot/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 319, in run_command
self.distribution.run_command(command)
File "/tmp/pip-build-env-7xavfwot/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1217, in run_command
super().run_command(command)
File "/tmp/pip-build-env-7xavfwot/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 987, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
File "/tmp/pip-build-env-7xavfwot/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build.py", line 132, in run
self.run_command(cmd_name)
File "/tmp/pip-build-env-7xavfwot/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 319, in run_command
self.distribution.run_command(command)
File "/tmp/pip-build-env-7xavfwot/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1217, in run_command
super().run_command(command)
File "/tmp/pip-build-env-7xavfwot/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 987, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
File "/tmp/pip-build-env-7xavfwot/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 84, in run
_build_ext.run(self)
File "/tmp/pip-build-env-7xavfwot/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 346, in run
self.build_extensions()
File "/tmp/pip-build-env-7xavfwot/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pybind11/setup_helpers.py", line 288, in build_extensions
ext.cxx_std = auto_cpp_level(self.compiler)
File "/tmp/pip-build-env-7xavfwot/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pybind11/setup_helpers.py", line 271, in auto_cpp_level
raise RuntimeError(msg)
RuntimeError: Unsupported compiler -- at least C++11 support is needed!
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for yolov4
Failed to build yolov4
ERROR: Could not build wheels for yolov4, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Comment: > Unsupported compiler -- at least C++11 support is needed!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm trying to install yolov4 via terminal on my VSCode. But i receive this error ERROR: Could not build wheels for yolov4, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects